Issue of mouse click on right side of the screen
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-05-31 18:40:40

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. Latitude E6230
Memory:                                      12.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-3320M × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               512.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            A20
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 23.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               Not Available
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.5.0-35-generic

Today after getting upgrade mouse click does not work on 2 cm of screen (no left nor right click works) This might be a resolution issue I guess. Right now checked changing each resolution. No solution. Please help.

is it the same with Wayland?  You also say GNOME version is not available? use gnome-shell --version in terminal to determine.
[edit] your question, don't add to comment trail.

GNOME Shell 45.2

WaylandEnable=true

Left & Right click started working after reboot the OS

Thank you so much

Next day morning again the same issue
